# I need to hand over a variable from one controller to another (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5

I need to hand over a Variable ($id) from my "KundenController" to my "ServerController" to link the id of "kunden" to "kunden_id" in my server colum.

Could you help me with that please? im totally stuck

```
 public function store() //KundenController
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name'=>'required',
        'RAM'=>'required',
        'CPUAnzahl'=>'required',
        'CPUBezeichnung'=>'required',
        'Festplatte1'=>'required'

    ]);
    $server = new Server;
    $kunden = new Kunden;

    $server->name = request('name');
    $server->RAM = request('RAM');
    $server->CPUAnzahl = request('CPUAnzahl');
    $server->CPUBezeichnung = request('CPUBezeichnung');
    $server->Festplatte1 = request('Festplatte1');

    $server->save();

    return redirect('/server/index');
}

 public function store() //ServerController
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name'=>'required',
        'RAM'=>'required',
        'CPUAnzahl'=>'required',
        'CPUBezeichnung'=>'required',
        'Festplatte1'=>'required'

    ]);
    $server = new Server;
    $kunden = new Kunden;

    $server->name = request('name');
    $server->RAM = request('RAM');
    $server->CPUAnzahl = request('CPUAnzahl');
    $server->CPUBezeichnung = request('CPUBezeichnung');
    $server->Festplatte1 = request('Festplatte1');

    $server->save();

    return redirect('/server/index');
}
```

so i need to get smth like $server->KundenID = request($kunden->id); but thats not working.
First time working with Laravel in PHP it would be kinda simple

Comment: are other request(something) methods working? did you try just request('id') in your KundenController?

Comment: That's not easily possible because it's not supposed to be and you're not supposed to do that. That's not what controllers are for. Extract the logic to a ServerRepository or encapsulate it behind a method on the Server class or let a ServerProvisioner-class handle it or something, so you can call it from anywhere. It's domain logic and it does not belong in the Controller.

Comment: @boroboris yes they are all working fine. But i need to link that two controllers to each other.

Comment: @Quasdunk thanks! Is their another good method to link the Collums to each other. I´m working on a simple NetworkingDoku and the Customer ID should link to a few Collums like Server/Workstations and they should link to Software and Useraccounts

Comment: @n1ghty Not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking about the database structure, how to get the authenticated user or about relationships between models? Have a look at the Laravel documentation, it's really instructive and should help you get going: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: The Database structure is fine. But i need a good way to link the forms to each other. So the Server ID is linked to a Costumer ID.

Comment: So you have a form where a user can create a server, right? When you post the form to `/servers`, you want to create the server from the given data and also set the user_id to the id of the authenticated user, right? That's as simple as what you have there, just add `$server->user_id = auth()->user()->id;`.

Comment: It´s not like a User Account which is posting. Right now everybody can insert Costumer Data. To the Costumer Data their belongs the Servers, the Workstations and so on. To the Server and Workstation Data their are Software and UserAccounts which belong to the Server/Workstations

Comment: Ok, so you have one form for customer data and server stuff. My first approach would be to separate the concerns. First, grab the customer-data and create the customer to get a customer_id: `$customer = Customer::create($request->only(...));`. Then, grab the server-data and create a server with the customer_id of the newly created customer. As I said, extract that logic to a class like CreateServer or maybe handle it within a Job (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#creating-jobs) - just get it out of the controller, think of a good name for it and make it a class.

Comment: Does both the store() function executing at same time??

Comment: @n1ghty Sorry, it's *really* hard to follow you when you just keep throwing in small pieces of the problem without actual context. I suggest you edit your question, show the relevant DB-structure and the form and then tell us what you are *really* trying to achieve (calling a controller method from another controller is obviously not the goal).

Comment: The Customers are already created. I can access them via {{ $kunde->id }} which creates a new page /kunden/{id}. Within this Page their is a new Sidebar with: New Server, New Workstation etc. and in this Links there are the Forms. As example /server/create or /workstatation/create. Now i need to get the variable {{ $kunde->id } into the form of /server/create to insert it into the database. The form inserts in the Controller. If i understood your post right i should seperate the Controller into a class and return the {{ $kunde->id } to the new class (for example createserver)

Comment: @n1ghty Oh, ok - so the customer is already created. Then you just need to pass their id to the view for /server/create or /workstation/create and e.g. add it as a hidden field to the form. Another approach (which I think fits better in this case) may be a different url-structure, like `kunden/{id}/servers/create` and `kunden/{id}/workstations/create` so you can accept the customer-id as a url-parameter in the controller. I hope this answers your question somehow. And yes, it's always a good idea to get the domain logic out of the controller.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i need. But i cant access the $kunden = Kunden::all(); and $kunden = Kunden::find($id); variables from the ServerController so i cant access these urls from the ServerController

Comment: @n1ghty Why wouldn't you? If you define the route like this: `Route::resource('kunden/{id}/servers', 'ServersController');` or, explicitly `Route::get('kunden/{id}/servers/create', 'ServersController@create');`, the `id` is passed automatically into the corresponding method on your ServersController, you just accept is as a parameter: `public function create($id, Request $request) { $customer = Kunde::find($id); }`.

Comment: Or even better, you can leverage [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding) and have it pass the actual customer object so you don't need to query it yourself. You just need to typehint it, for instance: `Route::get('kunden/{kunde}/servers/create', 'ServersController@create');`, and in your controller: `public function create(Kunde $kunde, Request $request) { echo "the customer is " . $kunde->name; }`

Comment: but then i cant display the form?                                                      
     public function create($id, Request $request)
    {
        $kunden = Kunden::find($id);
        return view('/kunden/{id}/server.create');
    }Route::get('/kunden/{id}server/create', 'ServerController@create') and the sidebar links to <li><a href="kunden/{id}/servers/create">Neuer Server</a></li> sorry <.< dont really get the laravel routing to 100% thats why i´m doing that project to learn it

Comment: @n1ghty Sure, why not? Just return the view for it. And after you enter the server-data, you post to `Route::post('kunden/{kunde}/servers', 'ServersController@store');` where you, again, have the `$kunde` available to create the server for: `$server->kunden_id = $kunde->id;`

Comment: @n1ghty Not exactly, you don't return `view('/kunden/{id}/server.create')`, you return the regular server-create-form and pass it the `$kunde`: `view(servers.create, ['kunde' => $kunde])`, and in your view, you link it from the sidebar with `<a href="kunden/{$kunde->id}/servers/create">`. Notice that view != route!

Comment: So, you have `Route::get('kunden/{kunde}', 'KundenController@show');`, which looks like this: `public function show(Kunde $kunde, Request $request) { return view('kunde.show', ['kunde' => $kunde]); }` where you return the main view for the customer including the sidebar for further actions. And in the sidebar, you add a link like `<a href="kunden/{$kunde->id}/servers/create">Neuer Server</a>`. Does that clear it up a little?

Comment: @Quasdunk Okay but right no i do a compact like compact('kunden');  in the public function show($id) do i just need to overide this? or is you function like the same just a laravel function not a php function

Comment: @n1ghty `compact('kunden')` is exactly the same as `['kunden' => $kunden]`. It's not a Laravel thing, it's just plain PHP. It creates an associative array with the name of the variable as the key and its value as the value for that key. Were you able to get it working? If not, I'd try to post an answer with how all works together. Apart from that, I highly recommend reading the Laravel docs. It's one of the best documented frameworks out there and it's really fun to read, so give it a shot!

Comment: Im trying right now but dont really get it :D That answer how it works together would be really great. Im reading the laravel docs since 1hour and tried a lot but i only get the NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: error

Comment: lemme just give you the infos you need: their are 3 folders kunden, layouts and servers. kunden : create, index, list, show, server: create, index and list (create is the form, index is the page the show the servers and list is the table to list the servers credentials later)

Comment: Route::get('/', 'KundenController@index');

Route::get('/kunden/create', 'KundenController@create');

Route::post('/kunden', 'KundenController@store');

Route::get('/kunden/{id}', 'KundenController@show');

Route::get('/{id}/server/create', 'ServerController@create');

Route::post('/{id}/server', 'ServerController@store'); and the code posted at the top of the page

Comment: I managed to got it working. But i got another question. Where to store my action at? <form method="POST" action="/kunden/{{$kunden->id}}/server"> oder just /server

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to associate products like Servers and Workstations with a customer, you first need a customer - obviously!

Since a customer is already created and the products are directly connected to them, one level of nesting routes seems to make perfect sense, so here's how your routes should look like:

```
Route::get('/kunden', 'KundenController@index');
Route::get('/kunden/create', 'KundenController@create');
Route::post('/kunden', 'KundenController@store');
Route::get('/kunden/{kunde}', 'KundenController@show');

Route::get('/kunden/{kunde}/servers', 'ServerController@index');
Route::get('/kunden/{kunde}/servers/create', 'ServersController@create');
Route::post('/kunden/{kunde}/servers', 'ServersController@store');
Route::get('/kunden/{kunde}/servers/{server}', 'ServersController@show');
```

In your Models, do:

**// Kunde**

```
public function servers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Server::class)
}
```

**// Server**

```
public function kunde()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Kunde::class)
}
```

> Have a look at the documentation for more details about relationships:
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Your controllers then should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Kunde;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class KundenController extends Controller
{

    /** list all customers */
    public function index()
    {
        $kunden = Kunde::all();

        return view('kunden.index', ['kunden' => $kunden]);
    }


    /** show the create form */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('kunden.create');
    }


    /** create the actual customer from the given data */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // validation...
        $this->validate(....)

        // use forceCreate or adjust the $fillable attribute
        // or set the properties one by one and then save.
        $kunde = Kunde::forceCreate([....]); 

        // redirect to the details page for the newly created customer
        return redirect("/kunden/{$kunde->id}");
    }


    /** show the customer details for the given customer */
    public function create(Kunde $kunde, Request $request)
    {
        return view('kunden.show', ['kunde' => $kunde]);
    }
}
```

And the ServersController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Kunde;
use App\Server;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ServersController extends Controller
{

    /** list all servers for the given customer */
    public function index(Kunde $kunde)
    {

        $servers = $kunde->servers;

        return view('kunden.server.index', [
            'kunde' => $kunde, 
            'servers' => $servers
        ]);
    }


    /** show the create form */
    public function create(Kunde $kunde)
    {
        return view('kunden.server.create', ['kunde' => $kunde]);
    }


    /** create the actual server from the given data */
    public function create(Kunde $kunde, Request $request)
    {
        // validation...
        $this->validate(....)

        // use forceCreate or adjust the $fillable attribute
        // or set the properties one by one and then save.
        $server = $kunde->servers()->forceCreate([...]); 

        // redirect to the details page for the newly created server
        return redirect("/kunden/{$kunde->id}/servers/{$server->id}");
    }


    /** show the server details for the given server */
    public function create(Kunde $kunde, Server $server, Request $request)
    {
        return view('kunden.servers.show', [
            'kunde' => $kunde,
            'server' => $server,
        ]);
    }
}
```

We are using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) here, so the `Kunde` and the `Server` are passed in automatically by Laravel according to their `id` in the URL.

Your layout structure should look like this:

// main layout file - layout.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    ....
    yield('content')

    ...
</html>
```

// template for customers and sub-resources - kunden/layout.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')

    <nav>
        <a href="/kunden/{{ $kunde->id }}/servers/create">Neuer Server</a>
    </nav>

    yield('customer-details')

@stop
```

// details page for a customer - kunden/show.blade.php

```
@extends('kunden/layout.blade.php')

@section('customer-details')

    The name is {{ $kunde->name }}

@stop
```

// server creation page for a customer - kunden/servers/create.blade.php

```
@extends('kunden/layout.blade.php')

@section('customer-details')

    <form method="POST" action="/kunden/{{ $kunde->id }}/servers">
       ...
    </form>

@stop
```

The naming is far from ideal, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! Got a question to that, Route::get('/', 'ServerController@index'); and Route::get('/', 'KundenController@index'); wouldn´t it display only the KundenController? But i need to show the Costumers at first

Comment: /kunden/kunden//servers/create  should be /kunden/5/server/create

Comment: <form method="POST" action="kunden/{{ $kunde->id }}/servers">

Comment: @n1ghty Yep, that was a copy-paste-mistake, fixed it.

Comment: The problem with the URL is still not really fixed... Got it over and over

Comment: @n1ghty Now that's a pretty vague problem description... What problem with what URL?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/kunden//servers/create thats the URL i get if i wanna visit the Server-Create form. It Should be http://localhost:8000/kunden/5/servers/create

Comment: @n1ghty This means that the `$kunde` is not resolved correctly in `ServersController@create`. This may be because a customer with that id does not exist or because the primary key is not `id`. Omit the typehint for `$kunde` and do a `dd($kunde)` to see what gets passed in.

Comment: Got it... The Variable was wrong... Mispelled it sorry <.< new error No query results for model [App\Kunden].

Comment: @n1ghty When you call `/kunden/{kunde}/servers/create`, Laravel will look for a parameter named `$kunde` on the associated controller method. If it's typhinted like in your case, it will know that you are looking for a `Kunde` with the id from the URL, so it will run `Kunde::find(...)` with that id and pass the result to the controller method. If it says that there were no query results then you probably just don't have a customer with that id or the id was empty in the URL. As I said,remove the typehint and check what gets passed in. You probably just did't link the URL correctly in your view

Comment: if i wanna create some data it always want to connect to /kunden/5/servers but it should be /kunden/5/server i cant the link to servers where does it get that?

Comment: @n1ghty What do you mean? Just change the route to what you want it to be in routes/web.php and then edit the links in your view-files (or even better, use named routes). Frankly, these are the most basic concepts of any web app, and the Laravel documentation does a pretty decent job walking you through it step by step. I could have answered every single question you've asked so far with a link to the docs. Why don't you just go ahead and read them yourself *thoroughly*? They even have a whole video series with an introduction to Laravel for free if you don't like reading!

Comment: is going for kunden/5/servers but it should be kunden/5/server and in web.php is everything fine... Route::post('/kunden/{kunden}/server', 'ServerController@store'); Theirs no place in my code where it could be servers instead of server i looked up every single file and line...

Comment: @n1ghty From where are you calling the URL? If it's in your browser, as already said, make sure you are linking to the correct route from your view. If there is no `kunden/{kunde}/servers` in your routes file and you still can call it, something is really off. Maybe it would be easier to just start a new project and go over every step from scratch. Since you said your goal is learning, this might be a good exercise.